# Update Multiple Values in a SQL query based on row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image: Current Table]

Is there a possible way only use SQL Update query to update July Data to August data? E.g. The Value of B in July should be updated to 12. Dimension Key is the primary key and Name is the "durable" key. CURSOR is allowed to use but not preferred.

Comment: Yes, use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`. There is no need for a `CURSOR` here.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current query attempt. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: for part of your where clause you should look up what BETWEEN does in a sql statement.  I am assuming this is for homework, so this is the only clue I will give you.

Comment: This is not a homework. I achieved it with loop in Python but need to figure out a way to integrate this into a stored procedure. I created this table to mask sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the table to itself to set different records of it in relation.

```sql
UPDATE A
SET A.Value = B.Value
FROM
    mytable A
    INNER JOIN mytable B
        ON A.Name = B.Name
WHERE
    A.Date = '2022-07-01' AND
    B.Date = '2022-08-01'
```

If you want to do this for corresponding days of the whole month you change the query like this

```sql
UPDATE A
SET A.Value = B.Value
FROM
    mytable A
    INNER JOIN mytable B
        ON A.Name = B.Name AND DAY(A.Date) = DAY(B.Date)
WHERE
    YEAR(A.Date) = 2022 AND MONTH(A.Date) = 7 AND
    YEAR(B.Date) = 2022 AND MONTH(B.Date) = 8
```

for a whole year you would write

```sql
...
        ON A.Name = B.Name AND
           DAY(A.Date) = DAY(B.Date) AND MONTH(A.Date) = MONTH(B.Date) - 1 
WHERE
    YEAR(A.Date) = 2022 AND
    YEAR(B.Date) = 2022
```

for all the years:

```sql
...
        ON A.Name = B.Name AND
           DAY(A.Date) = DAY(B.Date) AND
           MONTH(A.Date) = MONTH(B.Date) - 1 AND
           YEAR(A.Date) = YEAR(B.Date)
```

However, this simple approach does not work if the months are in different years. And also the months have a different number of days. Since I do not know your real use case I am not going into more detail here.

Instead of writing `SET A.Value = B.Value` you can simply write `SET Value = B.Value` since the target table is specified in `UPDATE A`.

Comment: Hi this is awesome and appreciated. In this way all the values in July will be updated. For performance purpose, adding A.Value!=B.Value in the WHERE  clause would solve that part?

Comment: The answer is not that simple. See: [UPDATE performance where no data changes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114360/update-performance-where-no-data-changes).